# Why an error occurs when setting the aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, aspect-ratio

I am trying to set the size of my blocks relative to the size of my cell (xib cell for UICollectionView).
I use the interface builder.

Xcode 10.1
Builds for "deployment target 12.1"
I tried to build and run on different emulators (from iphone 5s to ipad)

Everything works well without aspect ratio. But when I add them, an error appears during the build. Find what it is connected with and how I couldn’t fix it, tell me how I can fix it?

> Failed to update scene 'gTV-IL-0wX' with IBLayoutConstraint (x14), IBUIViewAutolayoutGuide (x1), UICollectionViewCell (x1), UIImageView (x1), and UILabel (x3).
>
> Exception name: NSGenericException
> Exception reason: Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:
> `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d7c0d0070 UILabel:0x7f8d7c0a4710'07.18'.height == 0.18*UICollectionViewCell:0x7f8d7c0a3070.height   (active)> view:<UILabel: 0x7f8d7c0a4710; frame = (11 154; 179 36); text = '07.18'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f8d7c06aec0>>`

[image: My constraints and error]

Comment: Have you done what the error message states?

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry, yes, of course, I forgot to attach. I added a message from the log and updated the post.